# Why my code not work in IE7 ( show/hide element )?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does my code not work in IE7 (show/hide element)?

First, it will show image and hide button.
When the box is checked, the image will hide and the button will show.

I tested in Chrome and Firefox, and they're OK, but in IE7 it does not work. How can I make it work?

***HTML***

```
<img id="thumbnail_image" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/d9a919813dac42adbd0e3106bc19bc04.png" style=" max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px; border: 1px dashed #ccc; ">
<input type="file" id="offer_image_1" size="30" style="float: left;" hidden >
<input type="checkbox" id="change_thumbnail_image" /> Change Image
```

***JS***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('change_thumbnail_image').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('thumbnail_image').hidden = this.checked;
    document.getElementById('offer_image_1').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
</script>
```

Comment: Try using "onclick" instead of "onchange".

Comment: it's OK, but on page load in IE button id="offer_image_1" not hidden ? , how can i do ?

Comment: That "hidden" attribute will have no effect. Add `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` to the "style" attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange` event on form elements usually doesn't fire in Internet Explorer until the user moves focus away from that control. There is also no `hidden` property on any HTML elements. Use the "onclick" event, and set the display property of the style object on the "image_thumbnail" to get the correct effect.

```
document.getElementById('change_thumbnail_image').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('thumbnail_image').style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.getElementById('offer_image_1').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

To make the "offer_image_1" element hidden on page load:

```
<input type="file" id="offer_image_1" size="30"
    style="float: left; display: none;">
```